# Programmatically accessing cProfile data

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile, pstats

I need to capture some python profiling data and generate a report.

While most of this component runs Python 3.5, to support a couple of legacy modules, we still have part of the system that runs 2.7.

In this instance, 3.5 invokes 2.7 via `subprocess.Popen()` and captures both `stdout` and `stderr` (which serve as data and log respectively).

I'm able to run cProfile inside the 2.7 process, write the resulting data to disk, and load it into pStats.

At this point, I can sort/filter and print to console. Unfortunately, as `stdout`/`stderr` are already in use, this isn't much help.

I'd also prefer a chance to format, inject source code snippets, etc.

So I need to interrogate the pStats class programmatically, build up a suitable report and then store it in our messaging system.

The documentation doesn't seem to indicate any way to extract data other that writing to console.

the `.stats` property looks promising but only contains an array of 3-tuples which omit lots of information.

How can I browse the data in pStats programmatically?

Specifically, I want to extract as a minimum:

- Source file/line number
- Cumulative time
- Exclusive time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not strictly a complete answer, but you might want to check out the [SnakeViz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) library (with which I am not affiliated). They do some visualisations of cProfile output, which presumably means they have a parser you might be able to hijack.

Comment: Thanks, that got me to this... https://github.com/jiffyclub/snakeviz/blob/4b5ffeec596db4462d4ff219151832951d273bf4/snakeviz/stats.py#L9